# Passing from Form to Query in Access/SQL/VB

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2007

Access 2007 / SQL / VB
I have a query:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfCR1
FROM PData
WHERE (((PData.DestID)='CR1') And (((PData.AnswerTime)>=Starting)<Ending+1));
```

I am trying to pass the variables Starting and Ending to the above query from the below form:

```
Starting = StartDate & " " & StartTime
Ending = EndDate & " " & EndTime
On Error GoTo Err_Command5_Click
Dim stDocName As String
stDocName = "CountOfCR1 : Query"
DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit
Exit_Command5_Click:
Exit Sub
Err_Command5_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Command5_Click
```

How can I pass Starting and Ending from my form to my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to refer to the form in the query:

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfCR1
FROM PData
WHERE PData.DestID='CR1'
And PData.AnswerTime Between Forms!MyForm!StartDate + Forms!MyForm!StartTime
                     And Forms!MyForm!EndDate + Forms!MyForm!SEndTime
```

It is nearly always best to use a form with the recordsource set to the query or an sql string rather than opening a query. With a form, you can use the Where argument of the OpenForm method.

Comment: PARDON THE FORMATING, I DONT KNOW WHY ITS NOT WORKING. My SQL Statement reads: SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfCR1 FROM PData WHERE PData.DestID='CR1' AND PData.AnswerTime Between Forms!MainForm!Starting And Forms!MainForm!Ending; Starting and Ending are date/time that is set in MainForm It still doesnt seem to work.

Comment: In what way is it not working? No data? Incorrect data? Error message? You have : PhoneData WHERE PData.DestID this cannot be correct, either the table is called PData or it is called PhoneData.

Comment: Its called Pdata, thats not the error.  i've changed that.  The query reports the wrong answer= 0.  It should respond with a few a number above records as there are a few records that fit the criteria of CR1 and between the two dates entered in the form.

Comment: Also, Starting and Ending are created in the MainForm by grabbing the info from DTPicker and putting it into: Starting = CDate(StartDate & " " & StartTime)
Ending = CDate(EndDate & " " & EndTime)

Comment: Try adding the forms reference to the select to see if the data is as expected, like so: SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfCR1, [Forms]![MainForm]![Starting] AS SDate, [Forms]![MainForm]![Ending] AS EDate
FROM PData

Comment: That didnt help. When i msgbox my "starting" variable, it shows that it is formated correctly (i think). 9/2/2010 11:10:17 AM is an example.....and here is my current SQL statement(ive changed the tables, so PhoneData is now correct): SELECT Count(*) AS CountOfCRC1, [Forms]![MainForm]![Starting] AS SDate, [Forms]![MainForm]![Ending] AS EDate FROM PhoneData WHERE PhoneData.DestID='CRC1' And PhoneData.AnswerTime Between Forms!MainForm!Starting And Forms!MainForm!Ending;

Comment: Figured it out.  I created a new text box and called it "Starting".  I just made in not visible.  I dont know why this needed to exist instead of just using the dim name Starting alone.

Comment: I assumed that starting and ending were textboxes. You cannot refer to variables in Jet SQL, other than through a function, which is not a good idea. Think of Access as two parts - the Jet/ACE database with queries, and the deployment tool with forms, code and so forth.

Comment: If you were to create a form, however, based on a query as I suggest in my answer, you could use the variables in the WHERE argument of the OpenForm method of the DoCmd object: `DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm",,,"AnswerTime Between " & Format(Starting, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn") & " And " & Format(Ending, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn")`

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I could not have done it without you.