# Adding a Form Variable to Data Environment Query

Tags: sql, vba, vb6

How can I include a variable from a Visual Basic Form to a Data Environment SQL Statement?

Here is the **query:**

```
SELECT * FROM Chores WHERE ChoresDate = DateofChores
```

I need the *DateofChores* variable to be passed to the Data Environment Query.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can grasp from your request you should be able to achieve this by referring to the form in the query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Chores WHERE ChoresDate = Forms!FormName!DateofChores
```

Another example given here: [Passing from Form to Query in Access/SQL/VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753346/passing-from-form-to-query-in-access-sql-vb)